# how can I add web view in VR mode?

Tags: aframe, react-fiber

how can I add web view in VR mode? what I mean is that would I be able to put a webpage on an aframe's plane or something like that so that I can use that webpage using Oculus or any VR headset?

I saw one React Three Fiber example, but don't how to achieve it in aframe.